# Scss for loop generated with space

Tags: css, sass

I have problem with sass code...

```
 @for $i from 1 through 3 {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) { 
        transition: all (0.2*$i)s ease; 
      }
    }
```

its compiled like this

```
label p:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all 0.2 s ease;
}
label p:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all 0.4 s ease;
}
label p:nth-child(3) {
  transition: all 0.6 s ease;
}
```

Need to remove space after time

thanx

Comment: cimmanon are you kidding me?

Comment: @for $i from 1 through 3 {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) { 
        transition: all (0.2s*$i) ease; 
      }
    }

Comment: you just have to bring the "s" into the multiplication, which will treat it as a unit. Also cimmanon is not wrong, since the solution's in the other link. Welcome to the cold, harsh world of stackoverflow!